# Is there a way to fold tables side by side in RMarkdown or quarto?

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto

Is there a way to wrap a single table in RMarkdown or quarto?

I often work with time series data and need to list them. I use HTML as the output format.

As an example, let's say I have one temperature measurement each day from January 1, 2022 to July 1, 2022.
This data has 182 lines of observations. I want to display this with an appropriate length of the data wrapped around it.

I used `{kableExtra}` for the example code to output in markdown for Stackoverflow, but I am not particular about the package for the table output.

```r
data <- tibble::tibble(
  date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2022-01-01"), to = as.Date("2022-07-01"), by = "day"),
  temp = rnorm(length(date), mean = 35.5, sd = 0.3)
)

# Here is the top of the table
head(data) |> 
  kableExtra::kbl(format = "markdown", digits = 1)
```

| date | temp |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 35.2 |
| 2022-01-02 | 35.5 |
| 2022-01-03 | 35.6 |
| 2022-01-04 | 36.3 |
| 2022-01-05 | 35.5 |
| 2022-01-06 | 35.5 |

<sup>Created on 2022-11-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: how about only showing a part of the table you want to show, i.e. truncate it to a shorter table? You use already `head()`. Does this not help? You can show the first 15 rows with `head(data, 15)` (note: `head()` defaults to n=6) or `data[1:15,] |> kable()`. There are other ways to filter specific rows of the tibble to your liking.

Comment: Yes, I am not aiming to display all the data. However, there are times when it is necessary to wrap a table, even partially. For example, what if I want to display 10 rows of data wrapped in 5 rows each?

Comment: There is an extensive answer below (kudos to Sing Song - really elaborated!) This should answer the "how to output". The point that sticks is what you mean with "wrap up in 5 rows each". If I do get you right, you are speaking about breaking a longer table into smaller (sub-)tables. The "manual" way of doing this is by creating multiple objects with the sub-tables of your liking and printing them one by one, e.g. `data[1:5,] |> kable(); data[6:10,] |> kable()`.

Answer (score 3):

I realized after editing this answer for an hour, my answer kind went off on a tangent. My answer has shifted to the question of how to do any kind of output folding.

If you want to do like 10 rows of data 5 rows each, I assume you mean like paginations? Then I have no clue how to do that.

If you want a partial table, I know that `dyplyr::tibble()` would print out the first 10 rows of data and abbreviates the rest. With `dyplyr::tibble(knitr::kable(your_table))` it would print tables, but in a plain text format like markdown tables.

I have switched to Quarto recently, it doesn't seem like they have any paginations feature like that either. Below I provided 3 methods that I know works with Rmd and probably will also work with Quarto.

**PS**:

- The first 2 method does **NOT** fold tables. But it will **always** fold plain text outputs.

###### Method 1: Scrollable Output using CSS Syling

Referencing to the [R Markdown Cookbook-7.4 Scrollable Code Blocks](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/html-scroll.html), use CSS stylings,

````
```{css, echo=FALSE}
pre {
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

pre[class] {
  max-height: 100px;
}

.scroll-100 {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: inherit;
}
```
````

````
```{r, class.Output="scroll-100"}
1:1000
```
````

**Output**:
[image]

###### Method 2: Scrollable Output using Pandoc’s Fenced Code Blocks

Referencing to the [R Markdown Cookbook-12.3 Scrollable Text Output](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/hook-scroll.html),

````
```{r}
options(width = 60)
local({
  hook_output <- knitr::knit_hooks$get('output')
  knitr::knit_hooks$set(output = function(x, options) {
    if (!is.null(options$max.height)) options$attr.output <- c(
      options$attr.output,
      sprintf('style="max-height: %s;"', options$max.height)
    )
    hook_output(x, options)
  })
})
```
````

````
```{r, max.height='100px'}
1:1000
```
````

**Output**:
[image]

###### Method 3: Collapses everything using HTML Button and Div Tag

Since you're using HTML, I guess one alternative is to try to use HTML. The below code will give you a bootstrap featured button that you can hide anything in there. You can also combine this method with method 1 or 2.

````
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#BlockName"> Show/Hide Tables</button>  
<div id="UniqueBlockName" class="collapse">  

    ```{r}
      you code to print tables
    ```

</div>
````

**Output**:
[image]

**Note**: This will have to include your source code (you can use `echo=FLASE`), and if your table is huge or you have something like a leaflet map inside it, it may cause lags when click to see it. In that case, I would suggest using the `head(your_table)` function instead.

**PS**: If you're not satisfied with `kableExtra`'s table output, maybe try `knitr::kable(you code to print table)` or `rmarkdown::paged_table(...)` or `pander::pander(...)`. I especially like the `pander` table for PDF output, it centers the table it supports Latex for col/row names. But depending on the HTML theme output, `pander()` is not always the best.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fully collapse/fold some content in Quarto (like code blocks with `#| code-fold: true`), you can put html `details` tags around it:

````
```{=html}
<details>
<summary>Click to expand</summary>
```

Your content that can be collapsed/folded.

```{=html}
</details>
```
````